# Oscar 2022 Topic Challenge: The nominees for Best Picture [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

The celebration of the [94th Annual Academy Awards ("Oscars")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/94th_Academy_Awards) might be a chance to discuss the contenders for the *Oscar for Best Picture* of the year. So we're starting a new **biweekly topic challenge. From 2022-03-28 00:00 UTC to 2022-04-10 23:00 UTC** we encourage you to ask any kind of on-topic question on the main site about **any of the *Oscar* nominees for *Best Picture*** (in particular [belfast](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belfast), [coda](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coda), [dont-look-up](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dont-look-up), [drive-my-car](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drive-my-car), [dune-2021](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2021), [king-richard](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-richard), [licorice-pizza](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licorice-pizza), [nightmare-alley](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nightmare-alley), [the-power-of-the-dog](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-power-of-the-dog) and [west-side-story-2021](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/west-side-story-2021)).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there was only a single 0-score question asked about the contending films (though, at least unarguably about the best of the nominated films):

### [Why did Baron Harkonnen ask this question?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/117274/49)

Which makes [*J Mac Brown*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/89899) the winner of this challenge by lack of competition.