# Is there any traditional challenge this year also?

Tags: discussion

I am talking about this [challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/)

Is there any traditional challenge this year also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [last](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4760/46980) [two](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4814/46980) Oscar challenges each only had a single eligible question, neither of which were upvoted, and in 2021 that question ended up getting deleted at -2.

There's been no word about it as far as I can tell, but I wouldn't be surprised if the challenges have been discontinued due to lack of participation. Certainly it's worth asking whether we *should* keep holding them if nobody's going to bother taking part.

Comment: I would like this to continue: I wasn't on movies.se at this point last year but would be interested in competing!